# how many n-length binary sequence problem

Tags: math, binary, sequence

how to find out the solution to this problem in python/java or any other language:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a programming problem at all. It seems like a homework problem for a discrete math class.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah, i need hint :)

Comment: It would be easy enough to write a Python program which would brute-force the answer for small `n`. For reasons that I can't quite articulate, I suspect that the answer has something to do with Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a program isn't a proof and you would still need to prove it, here is some Python code:

```
def zig_zag(seq):
    """tests if binary sequence seq satsifies zig-zag pattern"""
    for i in range(len(seq)-1):
        if (i%2 == 0 and seq[i] > seq[i+1]) or (i%2 == 1 and seq[i] < seq[i+1]):
            return False
    return True

def count_zig_zags(n):
    """counts the number of binary zig-zag patterns of length n"""
    count = 0
    for i in range(2**n):
        b = bin(i)[2:]
        if zig_zag(b): count += 1
    return count
```

For example:

```
>>> [count_zig_zags(n) for n in range(1,12)]
[2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233]
```

A proof would be via strong induction.

Comment: I think for the length 3, the output has to be 10, for example. Why 5?!

Comment: Is there any recursive solution?

Comment: How could the output for n = 3 be 10? 2^3 = 8, so even with no restrictions on the binary sequences it would have to be <= 8. The 5 binary sequences that satisfy the constraints are `000, 010, 011, 110, 111`.

Comment: For a recursive solution, note that a valid solution of length `n` can be extended to a valid solution of length `n+1` in either 1 way or 2 ways, and that the number that can be extended in 2 ways is the same as the number of valid sequences of length `n-1` (proof, which seems to require 2 cases depending on whether n is even or odd, not given).